# Injection in custom ConnectionProvider with CDI and Hibernate4

Tags: hibernate, cdi, weld

in Java EE 7 Project i need a custom ConnectionProvider, which call DB-Function with logged UserId, and set as DB-Session variables.

My Problem, I can't inject my logged User in MyConnectionProvider, but in all other Beans - without problem.

This is my ConnectionProvider:

```
@SessionScoped
@Named
public class MyConnectionProvider implements ConnectionProvider, Configurable, Serializable {

@Inject
private Logger log;

@Inject @LoggedIn
private User currentUser = null;
```

Here is class Login where is the currentUser initialized:

```
@SessionScoped
@Named
public class Login implements Serializable
{

@Inject
private Credentials credentials;

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager userDatabase;

private User currentUser;

//.....................................

@Produces
@LoggedIn
@Named
@SessionScoped
public User getCurrentUser()
{
  return currentUser;
}
```

and interface LoggedIn:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, PARAMETER,  METHOD, FIELD})
@Qualifier
public @interface LoggedIn {}
```

May be anyone has the same Problems ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate does not provide any injection support with these classes.  They are instantiated directly, and always are a singleton within your persistence unit.

You can still get this kind of functionality, just use the CDI utility class to look up your references.  `CDI.current().select(User.class, new LoggedInLiteral()).get()` where User.class is the class of the type you're expecting, and `LoggedInLiteral` is a qualifier instance.